# Валидатор ругается на <meta name="viewport">

Tags: html

[Валидатор](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Ctitle%3ETitle%3C%2Ftitle%3E%3Cmeta%20name%3D%22viewport%22%20content%3D%22width%3Ddevice-width%2C%20initial-scale%3D1.0%2C%20maximum-scale%3D1.0%2C%20user-scalable%3D0%22%3E&showsource) ругается на следующий код:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Это warning, ничего страшного тут нет

Comment: для меня нет, но клиенты бывают разные(

Comment: А если клиент скажет запретить зум и обойтись без warning'ов, то вы в безвыходном положении :D

Comment: когда человек не воспринимает объяснение, очень тяжело его переубедить в чем-то

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Валидатор ругается не на мета-тег, а на запрет зума. Никогда не запрещайте зум. Правильно было бы, например, вот так:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

[Проверка](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Ctitle%3ETitle%3C%2Ftitle%3E%3Cmeta%20name=%22viewport%22%20content=%22width=device-width,%20initial-scale=1.0%22%3E&showsource)

Comment: Как пользователь я бы предпочёл запрет зума, а то на телефоне очень легко случайно увеличить и не заметить, а потом страница едет)

Comment: Ну, вам никто не мешает вернуть обратно ) А вот у меня обратный опыт — у меня не очень хорошее зрение и когда на сайтах запрещен зум + мелкий текст, мне надо поднести смартфон очень близко к глазам, чтобы рассмотреть чо там.

Comment: Исходя из правил доступности (с точным значением могу ошибаться), пользователь должен иметь возможность увеличить текст на 100%.

Comment: я сам всегда за то , чтобы пользователю было удобно, но и за внешний вид также переживаю, но не всегда наши желания нормально воспринимают заказчики, которые требуют код без ошибок, ты им пытаешься что-то объяснить, они ни в какую, но в конце всегда говорят: "но вообще я в этом не сильно соображаю"

Comment: Так ведь нет ничего страшного в том, чтобы страница была увеличена на мобильном, в отличие от десктопного браузера там от этого ничто не может развалиться, т.е. внешний вид не испортится.

Comment: уже все норм, я использовал Ваш код и нормально все работает)